# .Net SQL Membership Provider custom provider property

Tags: asp.net, membership-provider

```
<profile>      
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>
  <properties>
    <add name="FirstName"/>
    <add name="LastName"/>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

I have the code snippet above in my webconfig file.  I am attempting to set the FirstName property in codebehind on a register.aspx page. Like this:

```
Profile.FirstName = ((TextBox)RegisterUser.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("FirstName")).Text;
```

VS says Profile is in System.Web.Profile Namespace.  I then use it like this "System.Web.Profile.FirstName", but says first name does not exist in System.Web.Profile.FirstName namespace.

How do I set the property and later retrieve it?

Comment: Can you post a little more of your code, specifically I'm looking to see what `Profile` is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Profile should be a property with an autogenerated class based on `System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase` which contains the members you defined in your web.config file. Here is the link on msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.profile.profilebase.aspx

But i can remember that i also had the problem, that the file is not generated by visual studio. I found [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/joewrobel/archive/2008/02/03/web-profile-builder-for-web-application-projects.aspx) where you can see a WebProfile generator as an extension for the build process. Maybe that can help you.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get strongly typed access to the profile items you need to use a tool such as the  [Web Profile Builder](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ProjectName=WebProfileBuilder&ReleaseId=980).

In Website projects Asp.net automatically creates the strongly typed proxy classes but they are not automatically created in Web Application projects.

Comment: Does using VS 2010 make a difference using the WebProfileBuilder?  I ask because I ran the WebProfileBuilder.  I added the Import Project line in my csproj.  When I opened the solution and compiled, I was not prompted to load my project normally.  Does installing the MSI and building project cause a WebProfile class to be created? Dont see anything created. What is the code to set/access profile properties. This does not seem to set it: System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase.Properties["FirstName"].Name = ((TextBox)RegisterUser.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("FirstName")).Text;

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

ProfileCommon p = (ProfileCommon)ProfileBase.Create(username, true);

p.FirstName = "firstname";

p.Save();

if the user already has a profile, the create call will return the existing profile, else it will create a new profile.

ProfileCommon is a autogenerated class.